# How remove pages word in url - domain/pages/disability-support in laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, routes

my url:- domain/pages/disability-support
i need  domain/disability-support

route :-
Route::any('/pages/{name}', 'PageController@pages')->name('pages');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to use an `route parameter` with page name. Like it:

Route:

```php
Route::any('/{name}', 'ProfileController@pages')->name('pages');
```

Controller:

```
<?php

...

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{    
    public function pages(Request $request, $name)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Route:

```
Route::any('/{name}', [
                'as' => 'pages',
                'uses' => 'ProfileController@pages',
            ]);
```

Controller:

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{    
    public function pages($name)
    {

    }
}
```